# Why $\frac{d}{dt} \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx} [ \frac{dy}{dx} ] \quad \frac{dx}{dt} $?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, intuition, visualization

Sources: [*Calculus: Early Transcendentals* (6 edn 2007)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0495011665). p. 206, Section 3.4. Question 95.
[*Elementary Differential Equations*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470383348) (9 edn 2008). p. 165, Section 3.3, Question 34.

> **Quandary:** If $y=f(x)$, and $x = u(t)$ is  a new independent variable, where $f$ and $u$ are twice differentiable functions, what's $\dfrac{d^{2}y}{\mathrm{d}t^{2}} $?

> **Answer:** By the chain rule, $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} $.  Then by the product rule,

> $\begin{align} 
> \dfrac{d^{2}y}{\mathrm{d}t^{2}} & \stackrel{\mathrm{defn}}{=}\dfrac{d}{\mathrm{d}t}  \dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}     
> \\ & = \color{forestgreen}{ \dfrac{d}{\mathrm{d}t} \dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} } & \dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} & +\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \quad \dfrac{d}{\mathrm{d}t} \dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}
> \\ & = \color{red}{\frac{d^{2}y}{\mathrm{d}x^{2}}(\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t})} &  \dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} & + \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \quad \frac{d^{2}x}{\mathrm{d}t^{2}}
> \\ & = \frac{d^{2}y}{\mathrm{d}x^{2}}(\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t})^{2} & &+\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \quad \frac{d^{2}x}{\mathrm{d}t^{2}}
> \end{align} $

Why $\color{forestgreen}{ \dfrac{d}{\mathrm{d}t} \dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} } = \color{red}{\dfrac{d^{2}y}{\mathrm{d}x^{2}}(\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t})}  $? Please explain informlly and intuitively.

Comment: It's just the Chain Rule... call $dy/dx$ by $F$ and differentiate $F(x(t))$ with respect to $t$ to get $F'(x(t))\cdot x'(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as a function of $x$; say it is $f(x)$. Then $x$ is also a function of $t$. So, by the *exact same* chain rule argument that you gave,
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{dy}{dx}\right]=\frac{d}{dt}[f(x)]=\frac{df}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}.
$$
But
$$
\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{dy}{dx}\right].
$$

Answer (score 0):

Just chain rule in action. Let $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx} = z$

So $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dy}{dx}) = \frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{dz}{dx}.\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx}).\frac{dx}{dt}$, as you wanted to prove.